# Index.js: Cannot read property 'dawgs' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm trying to use index.js feeded by a JSON response to populate a grid.

My JSON response is as following :

```
{"id":"0-nm7ee1ue9bzjbstn9ygv6lxr","size":29,"price":768,"face":"( .-. )","date":"Mon Jul 31 2017 04:28:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"1-ucdvpte68e22yw7w01j68ncdi","size":23,"price":115,"face":"( .o.)","date":"Sat Aug 05 2017 01:08:36 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"2-6ev861slycro0temr3vb98jjor","size":13,"price":421,"face":"( `·´ )","date":"Sun Aug 06 2017 17:08:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"3-mutgdpkeqipbe2evypfmbzkt9","size":35,"price":6,"face":"( ° ͜ ʖ °)","date":"Wed Aug 02 2017 19:30:29 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"4-fjimlap3tposcqib38lz93sor","size":16,"price":716,"face":"( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)","date":"Thu Jul 27 2017 02:23:56 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"5-7qlbahzmtzt77gpsvuh68khuxr","size":18,"price":483,"face":"( ⚆ _ ⚆ )","date":"Mon Aug 07 2017 21:43:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"6-f8k9eygn92hbzqp0dvx3jo47vi","size":37,"price":757,"face":"( ︶︿︶)","date":"Mon Jul 24 2017 07:59:49 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"7-i816dwwdy3kxv5c0hgz4zpvi","size":24,"price":915,"face":"( ﾟヮﾟ)","date":"Thu Aug 03 2017 04:14:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"8-w06tgl269c8qckt4j7vdq85mi","size":29,"price":309,"face":"(\\/)(°,,,°)(\\/)","date":"Thu Jul 27 2017 04:11:38 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
{"id":"9-jy6zjva7bdc2wl9vl05zpk3xr","size":21,"price":620,"face":"(¬_¬)","date":"Tue Jul 25 2017 13:54:51 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}
```

I created index.js file with the following content:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const RECEIVE_DAWGS = 'RECEIVE_DAWGS';

function receiveDawgs(json){
  const{dawgs} = json.data;
  return{
    type: RECEIVE_DAWGS,
    dawgs
  }
}

function fetchDawgsJson(){
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products', {responseType: 'stream'})
  .then(({data}) => { 
    const xdjson = data.split('\n').slice(0, -1)
    const json = xdjson.map((item, i) => JSON.parse(item))
    return json

    })

}

export function fetchDawgs(){
  return function(dispatch){
    return fetchDawgsJson()
    .then(json  => dispatch(receiveDawgs(json)))
  }
}
```

I'm encountering the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dawgs' of undefined
    at receiveDawgs (index.js:5)
    at index.js:27
    at <anonymous>
```

When I write index.js like this:

```
export const RECEIVE_DAWGS = 'RECEIVE_DAWGS';

function receiveDawgs(json){
  const{dawgs} = json.data;
  return{
    type: RECEIVE_DAWGS,
    dawgs
  }
}

function fetchDawgsJson(){
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products')
  .then(response => 
      response.json()

  )

}

export function fetchDawgs(){
  return function(dispatch){
    return fetchDawgsJson()
    .then(json  => dispatch(receiveDawgs(json)))
  }
}
```

I'm encountering the following error:

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 126
```

With this Unexpected token error, notice that character position is exactly at the begining of the second item in the json response.

When I change the fetchDawgsJson to limit the response to 1 item like this:

```
function fetchDawgsJson(){
  return fetch('http://genie:8000/api/products?limit=1')
  .then(response => 
      response.json()

  )

}
```

, I experience the same error as when using axios:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dawgs' of undefined
    at receiveDawgs (index.js:3)
    at index.js:23
    at <anonymous>
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.
Any advice or insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this is invalid JSON.

you are outputting a bunch of objects - they need to be wrapped into an array

further, you assume that the response will have an object with a dawgs property

```
const{dawgs} = json.data;
```

the implication is that data has to arrive as:

```
{
    "dawgs": [
{"id":"0-nm7ee1ue9bzjbstn9ygv6lxr","size":29,"price":768,"face":"( .-. )","date":"Mon Jul 31 2017 04:28:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)"},
{"id":"1-ucdvpte68e22yw7w01j68ncdi","size":23,"price":115,"face":"( .o.)","date":"Sat Aug 05 2017 01:08:36 GMT-0400 (EDT)"},
       .... more
     ]
}
```

and finally, when you have a `responseType: 'stream'`, the data prop on the response will contain a stream. are you using axios on the server?

Comment: thank you for this insight. I think I'm using axios on the server. perhaps I have it configured poorly? Is there a better way to verify?

Comment: the code you posted is server-side? if so, you need to pipe the stream but the data does not suggest a stream is required as its just plain json.

Comment: Yes it is server-side.  should I pipe the stream like this example i see from the axios npm page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) ?  :

// GET request for remote image 
axios({
  method:'get',
  url:'http://url',
  responseType:'stream'
})
  .then(function(response) {
  response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
});

Comment: it's not suitable as a stream... its normal data. stream normally is say, buffer / file read etc for non-blocking purposes.